# Twitter Archive Email Confirmation won’t send

Tags: twitter, twitter-archive

I want to download my Twitter archive, but the email with the link isn’t arriving in my inbox. I’m sure it’s not a problem with my email because I still receive Twitter notification emails.

Comment: Almost a year and the problem is not fixed yet.

Answer (score 3):

I had been having this same problem as well.

I saw a tweet that said if you have email notifications disabled, it won't send. Hopefully that will fix the problem. It didn't fix mine but it fixed several others'.

Answer (score 3):

For whatever reason, I found that the Yahoo address I was using would simply not accept the confirmation emails.  I tried adding Twitter as a safe sender to no avail; the emails never showed up in Spam or anywhere else.

I then changed my Twitter account to use another Yahoo address, and it worked.  The confirmation process for the new address was initiated by putting in that address on Twitter's Settings screen, and once confirmation had been performed, I requested my tweet archive, received it at the new address within minutes, then immediately changed my Twitter account's address back to the desired Yahoo address.

Now I can request an archive and the email comes in on the original address that was not receiving the emails before.  It seems that Twitter just needed the account's email address to get shaken up before it resumed working.

Comment: FWIW, this is the recommended workaround on the help center for email confirmation message-related issues.

Comment: This worked, I had to change my email first (I just added a +twitter to my gmail address)

Answer (score 3):

I've been having the same problem. I changed my email address on Twitter to one of my other addresses, got the email confirmation message and confirmed it, then changed it right back, then got another confirmation email. Once I confirmed that one, it allowed me to run my archive.

It seems like it just needed to get a little kick to get that email confirmation out.

Answer (score 0):

This is not instant. Depending on the size of your archive and the current processing queue, it will take some time before you receive the email.

> 3. When your download is ready, we'll send an email with a download link to the confirmed email address associated with your Twitter account.
>
> **Please note:** It may take a few days for us to prepare the download of your Twitter archive.

[Source](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20170160-downloading-your-twitter-archive).

Comment: I think he's talking about the first confirmation email, not the archive completed notification email.